# PowerShell Write-Progress while iterating over a hash GetEnumerator()

Tags: powershell, hashtable

If you are iterating over an array it is easy to provide feedback using `Write-Progress` , thus:

```
$items = @('a', 'b', 'c')
foreach ($item in $items) {
  Write-Progress -Activity 'Foo' -PercentComplete ($items.IndexOf($item) * 100 / $items.Count) -CurrentOperation $item
  Start-Sleep 2
}
```

Is there a similar trick that can be used when iterating over a hash?

```
$items = @{'x' = 'a'; 'y' = 'b'; 'z' = 'c'}
foreach ($item in $items.GetEnumerator()) {
  Write-Progress ...
  Start-Sleep 2
}
```

I can still access `$items.count`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get the index of the item from an the enumerator.

I appreciate that I can quite simply declare `$i=0` at the start and include `$i++` in the loop but is there another way?

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm unsure if I got it right. You can access the keys by `$item.Name` and the values by `$item.Value` inside the loop

Comment: There's no index, as hashtable does not preserve any order of items. Use a counter variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have the index.  In fact, it's a bit meaningless for hashtables as they are not stored in a set order like arrays.  You can simply do this:

```
foreach ($item in $items.GetEnumerator()) {
  Write-Progress -Activity 'Foo' -PercentComplete ($i++ / $items.Count *100) -CurrentOperation $item.key
  Start-Sleep 2
}
```

If you're likely to run the code multiple times in one session, zero the count before the `foreach` with `$i = 0`.

If you do want the items processed in the order you added them, then add the `[Ordered]` attribute to your hashtable:

`$items =  [Ordered]@{'x' = 'a'; 'y' = 'b'; 'z' = 'c'}`

This will allows you to index into the hashtable (e.g. `$thirdItem = $items[2]`), but doesn't provide anything like the `IndexOf()` method, so you'll need to stick with the counter variable.